# Why doesn't my iPad support Low Battery Mode?

Tags: ipad, battery, ios

As advertised with the release of iOS 9, Low Battery Mode can be activated on most modern iPhones to conserve power.

My question is, why doesn't the iPad support Low Battery Mode? It would seem to have the capability to – is there an official or proven answer as to why not?

*(I am using an iPad Air 2)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Why' is always difficult to answer.

That it doesn't appear to work on iPads would seem to be of concern to many people, but there doesn't appear to be any answer as to why.

See [Where’s The Low Power Mode in iPad, iOS 9 Users Want To Know](http://ios9news.net/cant-find-low-power-mode-settings-in-ipad/) or
[Low Power Mode Not Available on iPad in iOS 9: No Solution Till Now](https://www.igeeksblog.com/low-power-mode-not-available-on-ipad/) & others on Google. No-one seems to have any answers.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers try to answer the question as asked.

---

2022 update:

*[Low Power Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205234)* finally became available on iPads starting with **iPadOS 15**.

*(iPads running older versions of iOS, back to at least iOS 11, can [enable it](https://www.google.com/search?q=lpm%20enabler) if they are jailbroken.)*

Answer (score 0):

iPads already have so much battery life, and generally they are not used as a means for emergency communication, like the iPhone. There would be more of a need for iPhones, because it can be more costly if they die. I also think Apple wants iPads to always be running at full power, and low power mode disables some features that decrease CPU usage and such things like that. That is my speculation at least.